# This is a program to search a number and also display its index position if found in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

This is a C++ program to search a number and also display its index position if found in an array.
Program works fine. I just wanted to ask why we used k=1 in if statement because if we don't use it, then program won't work. Please explain the significance of k=1 in 2nd for loop in if statement.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n;
cout<<"Size of Array: ";
cin>>n;
int arr[n];
cout<<"Type Elements of Array: ";
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
cin>>arr[i];
}
int k;
cout<<"Enter No to be found: ";
cin>>k;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
if(arr[i]==k)
{
    k=1;
    cout<<"No is found at index position: "<<i<<endl;;    
    break;
}
else
{
    cout<<"No is not found"; 
    break;   
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That program won’t work *regardless* of whether that line is in there.

Comment: _"Program works fine."_ - no, it doesn't work at all. It will only ever check the first number and break out of the loop. Not to mention that `int arr[n];` is non-standard C++ and won't work on all compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do a linear search, there are some points I would like to clarify..

1. Never use `int arr[n]` using `cin` by user, it may work in yours, but not all compilers support it. Always allocate memory to the array statically like `arr[10]` or `arr[20]`
2. You are changing `k` which is the number that is to be found, I cannot understand why are you changing `k` . This is the number that is to be searched, you are mistakenly interpreting `k` as a `flag` variable, but it is **NOT**. Never try to change the input variable from the user.
3. Your program will only work, if the number you are searching is at `0th` index, because, after that you are literally breaking from the loop in both `if` as well as `else` condition.
4. Here is a link to a better linear search code in c++, I hope it will clear your concepts [C++ Linear Search](https://codescracker.com/cpp/program/cpp-program-linear-search.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the `k=1` statement. It lies in your logic of the else block.

Consider this:

```
n = 5
arr = [12, 2, 3, 14, 5]
k = 3
```

So initially `i` in the for loop starts from `0`

It checks for equality:

```
Is arr[i] == k ? 
   arr[0] == 3 ?
   12 == 3?
```

This is `false`, so your program goes to the else block, where it prints that the number was not found and breaks from the for loop. So essentially you are not checking all numbers, just the first one.

PS: Try and find a working logic for this on your own, it will be a good exercise and improve your understanding if you are getting started with programming (Hint: There are multiple ways, either through a flag variable or using the loop variable, etc). When your program doesn't work as you wanted it to, perform a dry run like I did on top.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for the dynamic allocation of the array. Secondly, there is a mess with your if-else block. It checks only the first number in the array and then proceeds to the else portion. Your program can work fine but you should make sure that it searches the complete array for the number to be searched. You can do it by just removing the else part:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if(arr[i]==k)
{
    cout<<"No is found at index position: "<<i<<endl;;    
    return 0;
}
}
cout<<"No is not found.";
return 0;
```

[image]